# How do you detect iPhone5 in PhoneGap?

Tags: iphone, cordova

Is there an easy way to detect if my app is running on an iPhone5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use the build in device.model part of PhoneGap

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_device_device.model.md.html#device.model

Comment: Cool - didn't know that was there! :D

Comment: I suggest the docs from here which are more up to date: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device/blob/c6e23d8a61793c263443794d66d40723b4d04377/doc/index.md

Answer (score 1):

Why yes, there is...

```
function isIphone5() {
  return device.name.match(/iPhone/i) != null && 
    window.innerWidth == 568 || window.innerHeight == 568;
}
```

Comment: why are you repeating the answer provided?

Comment: @ClintonWard I don't understand your question.